# ansible privilege issue on remote server

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running the following task to run a debian package on an ubuntu 14 OS using Ansible 2.1 but getting the exception copied below.  The remote user does have sudo privileges on the remote machine.

```
- name: run dpkg
  shell: dpkg -i {{ debian_build.stdout }}
  become: true
  become_user: ubuntu 
  become_method: sudo
```

**error**

```
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "dpkg -i /home/ubuntu/test-server_0.1.0-7c47d103f8da21045e3ee817529eb84a0aa79723_all.deb", "delta": "0:00:00.002444", "end": "2016-10-10 14:33:32.014887", "failed": true, "rc": 2, "start": "2016-10-10 14:33:32.012443", "stderr": "dpkg: error: requested operation requires superuser privilege", "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": [], "warnings": []}
```

Comment: I was able to run it as sudo dpkg -i {{ debian_build.stdout }}.  Wondering why the become section is not being used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this;

```
become: true
become_user: ubuntu 
become_method: sudo
```

Is the equivelant of doing this on shell:

```
myuser$ sudo su ubuntu
ubuntu$
```

You are using sudo to switch to a non-privileged user account. "Ubuntu" does not have access to run dpkg without invoking sudo, which is why your playbook works if you put sudo in your shell command.

You also shouldn't be using become to switch to a unprivileged user per Ansible best practices:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user

You should run this playbook as the correct user to begin with by using remote_user for example.

Comment: I will switch to root as opposed to ubuntu - or is there a better way?

Comment: If you need to run dpkg you need to be root. You can just do "become: yes" and this will (by default in ansible) switch you to root.